# Cannot find axios-jsonp

Tags: vue.js, axios, jsonp

I installed axios-jsonp, but the error saids there is no jsonpAdapter.
Could someone help me?

I use Vue.js and I want to get data from API.

error: Require statement not part of import statement.

```
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const jsonpAdapter = require("axios-jsonp");
    const getProductList = async (inputValue: string) => {
      const appId = <myappId>;

      axios({
        url:
          "https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V3/itemSearch?appid=" +
          appId +
          "&query=" +
          inputValue,
        adapter: jsonpAdapter,
      });
    };
```

package.json

```
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "vue3-sales-app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.2.2",
        "core-js": "^3.8.3",
        "jsonp": "^0.1.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.13",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
        "vuex": "^4.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.8",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
        "axios-jsonp": "^1.0.4",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "typescript": "~4.5.5"
      }
    },
```

I tried npm install axios-jsonp

Log:

> $npm install axios-jsonp
>
> added 392 packages, changed 1 package, and audited 1024 packages in 5s
>
> 112 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> 15 low severity vulnerabilities
>
> To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
> npm audit fix --force
>
> Some issues need review, and may require choosing a different
> dependency.
>
> Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: [axios-jsonp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-jsonp) is not listed as one of your dependencies. Use `npm install axios-jsonp` or `yarn add axios-jsonp` to install the package (depending on which package manager you are using)

Comment: Thank you, I tried the command by npm, but still dependencies hasn't changed.

Comment: Try `npm install axios-jsonp --save-prod`